# How can an inactive reserved IP address be used by another device on Windows server? Shouldn’t it be reserved?

Tags: windows, dhcp, windows-server, dhcp-server

I freshly set up DHCP server on Windows Server 2022 and create in advance IP reservation for devices.

At this stage, all devices concerned by this reservation are not yet connected, so IP reservation is on inactive state.

Then, I tried to test it by connecting a new device that is not in the list of reservation and the result that I get is that this new device get an IP address of an inactive reserved IP.

Why did it do that? Could anyone help me to understand this case?

Comment: The possible cases as I can see are : Duplicate MAC address, duplicate computer name, or static IP set in the new device itself.